# Add Page bookmarks to an existing PDF using iTextSharp using C# code

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, bookmarks

My requirement is same as described in this question: [Bookmark to specific page using iTextSharp 4.1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360946/bookmark-to-specific-page-using-itextsharp-4-1-6)

I tried the answer, but the last line gives my the following error:

> Can not implicitly convert `ArrayList` to `IList<Dictionar(strin,object)>`

I am not sure how to correct it.

The line that gave error is, in the Answer 1 of above link

```
wri.Outlines = bookmarks
```

I modified the example like this:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> testData = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>(100);
// Just Sample data for understanding.
//for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
//{
var test = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Action", "GoTo"},
    { "Title", "Page1 0 H 0" },
    {"Page", "1 XYZ 0 " + h + " 0" }
};
testData.Add(test);
//}
wri.Outlines = testData;
```

Now after adding the bookmarks, I'm unable to open the PDF because the file has been corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consult the [official documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book).

Bookmarks are discussed in [Chapter 7](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=7) where you'll find the [BookmarkedTimeTable](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=140) example. As you're working with iTextSharp (C#), not iText (Java), you'll want to look up the corresponding example in [the list of examples ported to C#](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/178), more specifically [BookmarkedTimeTable.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter07/BookmarkedTimeTable.cs).

**Update after you updated the question:**

Your error indicates that `testdata` isn't really of type `IList<Dictionar(string,object)>`; note that I've added a **g** to **strin** assuming that this is a typo in your question, not in your actual code.

Please start with the example from my book, and then change that example gradually until you break that code.

**Update based on extra comment:**

When a PDF is digitally signed, there is a limited number of operations that may (or may not) be allowed. See [Which operations are allowed on a digitally signed PDF?](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/digitalsignatures/whatbreakssignature) Adding bookmarks is not an allowed operation, so you'll have to remove all signature fields before applying the change. Depending on whether or not you want to keep the empty signature field or completely remove the field, you'll use either the method `clearSignatureField()` or `removeField()` passing the name of a signature field as parameter. You can get an `ArrayList` of names using the `getSignatureNames()` method (see [`ÀcroFields`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html)).

Comment: Thank you for the help.... I modified my code with the help of BookmarkedTimeTable.cs , but could not understand the "dest" file ref, In the comment section it is mentioned that -- Manipulates a PDF file src with the file dest as result but in code i could not find any ref abt dest, correct if I am wrong...

Comment: I managed to solve it with the help of your corresponding Java sample, Thanks a lot....

Comment: Please help me to resolve this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877294/apply-formatting-to-pdf-bookmarks-using-itextsharp

Comment: My program stopped working when it came to Digitally signed PDF, on googling i found that no changes are allowed after a document is  digitally signed, my requirement is to add bookmarks for a digitally signed document, but need not be the on the original, instead a copy would do , how to do that ? Pleas help...

Comment: Can you please give your answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308383/how-to-redact-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: I voted to close that question as it's too broad. The question isn't suited for StackOverflow (as documented in the StackOverflow FAQ). Please start by reading http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf

Comment: @user3122606 How you managed, is it possible we can import the bookmark via xml to pdf?

Comment: @MacDaddy, Did you tried the Itextsharp method? It really worked for you. I am also looking same thing.

Comment: @NachiappanR You are *hijacking* a question dating from 2013. **Do Not Do That!** If you have a question, for instance, if you have tried what is explained in this post, and if it doesn't work, explain what you have tried *in a new question* and explain the problem you are experiencing. Saying "I am also looking *for the* same thing" in a comment, usually doesn't result in an answer. It only annoys people, especially since you can find all the C# examples at the bottom of [this page](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-7).

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLowagie, Here my team already posted the tried one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993783/how-to-import-bookmark-from-xml-to-existing-pdf) but did not get any help that`s why I inquired here. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I see the question. It's as if you didn't even read the documentation. That's probably why no one cared to answer that question. You have a whole team and no one did an effort visiting the official iText web site.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it an actual ArrayList of Hashtables:

```
            var outlines = firstComponentPages.Select(x => new Hashtable()
            {
                {"Title", x.Value},
                {"Action", "GoTo"},
                {"Page", $"{x.Key} Fit"}
            }).ToList();


            var outlinesArrayList = new ArrayList();
            foreach (var outline in outlines)
            {
                outlinesArrayList.Add(outline);
            }
            copy.Outlines = outlinesArrayList;
```