# Apply Formatting to pdf bookmarks using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

This is further to my question [Add Page bookmarks to an existing PDF using iTextSharp using C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702728/add-page-bookmarks-to-an-existing-pdf-using-itextsharp-using-c-sharp-code)

With the guidence of Bruno Lowagie i managed to add pdf bookmarks using iTextShrp, but now i need to add color and bold formatting to the bookmarks.

Please help...

I am sure that it is possible , becuase i used ExportToXML to retrieve an already formatted bookmark, then it is having formatting info as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in my previous answer, I would like you to [please read the documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book).

What you are asking is explained in the [CreateOutlineTree](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=139) example. If `bookmark` is of type `PdfOutline`, you can change the style and font like this:

```
 bookmark.setStyle(Font.BOLD);
 bookmark.setColor(BaseColor.BLUE);
```

If you look at [the C# port of the example](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter07/CreateOutlineTree.cs), you'll discover a slight difference in iTextSharp:

```
 bookmark.Style = Font.BOLD;
 bookmark.Color = BaseColor.BLUE;
```

Comment: Thank You...really sorry to say that somehow i missed to find it myself..will be more careful next time...

Answer (score -1):

I've had better luck adding hyperlinks and internal bookmarks to PDFs using a VB DLL and DynamicPDF.