# How to redact PDF using iTextSharp?

Tags: pdf, itext

I want to programatically redact a PDF file using my C# code. I know that it is hard. Is it possible using itextsharp ? or what is the alternative.

Comment: Do you mean true redaction or merely putting some black blobs onto the page? The latter is easy to do; for the former you can use iText(Sharp) as framework to retrieve contents and write them back again with the appropriate changes, but your task still is enormous.

Comment: Thank you. My requirement is the marked/removed text should not appear in print / view of the pdf, is it possible with the one called black blobs ? Please guide.

Comment: *Black blobs* was meant metaphorically to describe the process of just painting a black rectangle (or some similar form) over the text. The text beneath won't appear in print and wont be immediately visible in a PDF viewer. But it will be there, still, and can be extracted e.g. by copy & paste. If that's ok, I'll describe how to do it.

Comment: Yes Its ok, Kindly provide details/ sample code. Thank You

Comment: Ok. How exactly are you given the coordinates of the areas to redact? As a collection of rectangles? Quadrilaterals? Generic paths?

Comment: The PDF has been viewed using the ActiveX control AxAcroPDF, the user will be selecting the area for redaction using Mouse. This is the scenario. Sorry I am not familiar with the specifications of Quadrilaterals or Generic path.

Comment: Please clarify in which form you have those areas. As you say that *the user will be selecting the area for redaction using Mouse* I assume you have some set of coordinates of some rectangles?

Answer (score 0):

As the OP clarified in comments to the Question:

> the marked/removed text should not appear in print / view of the pdf

Thus, here a simple solution which is merely painting a black rectangle over the text. The text beneath won't appear in print and wont be immediately visible in a PDF viewer. But it will be there, still, and can be extracted e.g. by copy & paste.

Furthermore, as I am more at home with Java, I provide code in Java for iText. It should be easy to port to iTextSharp, though, replacing `getX` by `GetX` or `X`, `setX` by `SetX` or `X`, and `method()` by `Method()` and using some .Net stream instead of the `FileOutputStream`:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("source.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("target.pdf"));

PdfContentByte content = stamper.getOverContent(1);
content.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);

// Do this for every rectangle given as x, y, width, heigth
content.rectangle(100f, 600f, 200f, 100f);
// Done

content.fill();

stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: Thank You, This is perfectly okay as long as i am able provide the co-ordinates correctly,but i am not able to provide/capture exact co-ordinates especially becuause it is depending on zoom level of the viewer control. Also i came to know that Acrobat SDK is now free, then can i used it for performing the redaction ? Or getting the actual co-ordinates from a PDF viewer control ?

Comment: I have no idea what you can do with that SDK and how you can extract correct coordinates from that viewer control. If you want to use external components, e.g. iText(Sharp), though, they obviously need to know the correct coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Redaction capabilities have recently been added to iTextSharp 5.5.5. See also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037282/how-to-create-and-apply-redactions?lq=1) and [change log](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/555)

Comment: Please be aware that this feature is a recent addition and still under development to become usable in real security contexts.